# TinyMCE - disable standard save button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I try to disable programmatically the standard "save" button of the save plugin

```
tinymce.init
  ({
    selector: '#editorMain',
    plugins: "save,code,textcolor,charmap,searchreplace,paste,wordcount",
    height: 400,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('keyup',function(e){
            console.log(getStats('editorMain').chars);
            var body = tinymce.get('editorMain').getBody();
            var currentValue=tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
            var currentCharsCount=getStats('editorMain').chars;
            var limit=10;
            var diff=limit - currentCharsCount;
            if (diff>-1)
            {
                $("#chars_left").html(diff + " characters left");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#chars_left").html("Your comment is too long");
                // here should we disable the save button
            }

        });
    },
```

I googled for a solution and found that in version 3.x there was an object called "ControlManager". This has been removed in version 4 (the one I currently use)

According to the documentation the following should be implemented to do that:

```
// In TinyMCE 4 you can use the simpler stateSelector setting
editor.addButton('SomeButton', {
    text: 'My button',
    stateSelector: 'a'
});
```

but how can this work for the "save" button ? the save button comes when I use the "save" plugin, this does not have to be programmatically added.

Answer (score 1):

well that was a tough one. This:

```
    tinymce.activeEditor.theme.panel.find('toolbar *')[1];
```

enables to access the button. then the ".disabled(1)" method.

That's a pity that we cannot access the elements using their names or ids...

Comment: Thanks for your advice laloune.Here is my use case for enable/disable a toolbar's button http://fiddle.tinymce.com/p3faab

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the functionality of the save plugin simply remove it from the list in the `plugins:` init options. Use the list shown here.

```
tinymce.init
  ({
    selector: '#editorMain',
    plugins: "code,textcolor,charmap,searchreplace,paste,wordcount",
    ....
```

Comment: I do actually  want the functionality, I just need to disable the save button depending on the number of chars in the textarea, meaning: default activated, if limit reached deactivated.

Comment: The class `tinymce.ui.MenuButton` (or one of its parent classes) may be what you are looking for. This class has a disabled method that sets/gets the disabled state on the control: `disabled(state:Boolean)`

Comment: The Save plugin has a `save_enablewhendirty` option that, when set true, disables the button until modifications are made. With that set, you might be able to bind to the editor change event and then use `editor.isNotDirty` to force the editor's state to clean until the max character count is reached. But forcing NotDirty might mess with the undo/redo state too. So, you're probably going to have to write a custom plugin to be used instead of Save. Looking at the Save plugin source code might be a good starting place if you go down the roll-you-own-plugin path.